# How to set Session length for a User in Clearance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

How do I kill the session cookie for a user that closes their browser and or a day passes in Clearance?

I do see the following config vars, but I believe the cookie expiration is for the general cookies, not for the session cookie?

```
Clearance.configure do |config|
  config.cookie_domain = ".trajectsku.com"
  config.cookie_expiration = lambda { |cookies| 1.year.from_now.utc }
end
```

Comment: It seems oddly specific to be any kind of general cookie setting.

Comment: But is it strange that the default is for one year? That implies general storage, ie. preferences. And a hashed session cookie is stored separately. Unless I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [clearance docs](https://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/clearance/master/Clearance/Configuration#cookie_expiration-instance_method) do explain that cookie expiration is what you are after. If you want the cookie to expire with the browser session, you should set the lambda to return nil like so:

```
Clearance.configure do |config|
  config.cookie_domain = ".trajectsku.com"
  config.cookie_expiration = lambda { |_cookies| nil }
end
```

Comment: So this does work, but my question was the specific length of the session, ie. "a day passes" = 24.hours, but using these settings for a length of time does not work. In fact, every refresh of the browser resets the cookie expiration to be my setting, so it never reaches that time.

Comment: The cookie expiration is reset every time it is used Within the validity period as it is deemed to be as good as a valid sign in.

Comment: That totally makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.